# How to make the where clause get 'id' from multiple values not just single ones in a column (php & sql)

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, explode, implode

i am trying to make my select statement go through my columns which contains multiple values eg "1,2,3" etc. Here is my Select statement

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files where departmentid=".$_SESSION['deptid']."";

$deptids = implode(',', $_POST['deptid']);
```

As you can see i take in multiple values into the deptid column. Select statement above is meant to show files related to a particular department, which works fine in single values columns but doesn't pick columns that has multiples values.

For instance if "$_SESSION['deptid'] = 4, and a column in table "files" has "2,1,4,5" it doesn't pick it only picks columns with "4". Thank you very much.

Comment: You shouldn't put multiple values in a column in the first place. You should put them in multiple rows of another table, with a foreign key to this table.

Comment: Until you fix that, use `FIND_IN_SET()`. See the details at the linked question.

Comment: thanks @Barmar i appreciate